# Ruby - Sort array by class type

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, class, sorting

Say I have an array of multiple class types

```
array = [ 1, "1", "one", true, { one: "one" }, :one ]
```

I want to sort this array by the class type in alphabetical order. For example `:one.class => Sybmol` would be ordered after `1.class => Fixnum`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: A few things: are you asking to sort by the class name string reverse lexicographically? What is the exact output you want for this input array and why are symbols less than fixnums? Second, having an array with multiple types like this is often an antipattern, so this could be an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You may want to reconsider whether your application should be relying on this design. Lastly, please show an attempt to avoid the post being closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) which accepts a block where you can invoke `class` and `to_s` on the receiver:

```
array.sort_by { |e| e.class.to_s }
# [{:one=>"one"}, 1, "1", "one", :one, true]
```

Comment: This code is not only concise, but also fairly optimized for speed as well. Do not be tempted to use symbols instead of strings - it will only make it *slower*, because it require one extra cast (cannot cast `Class` as `symbol`, need a `string` intermediate). So do **not** use this (slower): `array.sort_by { |e| e.class.to_s.to_sym }`

Answer (score 1):

If `array` were large and performance were important you might write the following.

```
array.group_by(&:class).sort_by { |k,_| k.to_s }.flat_map(&:last)
  #=> [{:one=>"one"},  1,    "1",  "one", :one,    true]
  #        Hash     Integer String String Symbol TrueClass
```

The steps in the calculation are as follows.

```
h = array.group_by(&:class)
  #=> {Integer=>[1], String=>["1", "one"], TrueClass=>[true],
  #    Hash=>[{:one=>"one"}], Symbol=>[:one]} 
a = h.sort_by { |k,_| k.to_s }
  #=> [[Hash, [{:one=>"one"}]], [Integer, [1]], [String, ["1", "one"]],
  #    [Symbol, [:one]], [TrueClass, [true]]] 
a.flat_map(&:last)
  #=> [{:one=>"one"}, 1, "1", "one", :one, true]
```

See [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) and [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

Letting `n` be the number of elements in `array` and `m` being the number of unique classes represented by the elements of `array`, the computation complexities of each component of the calculation are as follows.

```
group_by(&:class)         : O(n)
sort_by { |k,_| k.to_s }  : O(m*log(m))
flat_map(&:last)          : O(m)
```

By contrast, a conventional sort has a computational complexity of `O(n*log(n))`.

For the example of `array` given in the question,

```
n = array.size
  #=> 6
m = array.map(&:class).uniq.size
  #=> 5
```

Clearly, the conventional method of sorting would be fastest in this case. If, however, `n` were large and `m` relatively small, relative computational speed would be determined by `O(m*log(m))` versus `O(n*log(n))`, giving a large advantage to the method I proposed.

Note that this approach could be taken in any situation where elements `e` of a collection are to be sorted by a method `m` such that the number of unique values of `m(e)` is relatively small when compared to the size of the collection.